# Accessing hidden field values using Ruby Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, www-mechanize

I am trying to access the form values of hidden fields so I can set them or retrieve them.

I tried the `form.field_with()` method as well as just `form.fieldname` and cannot figure out how to get a reference back for a hidden field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you just do:

```
form['foo'] = 'bar'
```

That goes for all kinds of form fields, not just hiddens.